# masking input special character using Angular 8

Tags: regex, angular, special-characters, input-mask

I need to display credit card number on input field that looks like bullet special character:

```
4444 •••• •••• 4444
```

Im trying using pipe in Angular, and if can I want to avoid any input mask plugins,
this is what I had tried so far:

**mask.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'mask'
})
export class MaskPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, showMask :boolean): string {
    if (!showMask || value.length < 16) {
      return value;
    }
    return '-XXXX-XXXX-' + value.substr(0, value.length - 16);
  }

}
```

I not sure how to add special character (bullet character) on pipe, I could use some guidance and suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: It's not clear where is the problem. Your code is almost fine, you need to return the first 4 chars from the value, add the special chars you want and then  add just the last 4 chars from the value.

Comment: If the issue here simply the generation of the • characters?

Comment: yup, i not sure how to simply the bullet character in pipe

Comment: You could just have 4 input boxes and make the two in the center type=password and use the browser's native functionality. Then join the field values later.

Comment: @Hayden, can you please show some code as I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You just need to extract the right part of the card number. I have also added a check to convert the value to a string if the value you pass in is a number. The unicode character for bullet points is `&bull;`. In order to display this in your template, you will need to pass the value through the pipe using the `innerHTML` tag.

Try this.

```js
transform(value: string, showMask :boolean): string {

    if (typeof value === "number") {
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }

    if (!showMask || value.length < 16) {
        return value;
    }

    return `${value.substr(0, 4)} ${'&bull;'.repeat(4)} ${'&bull;'.repeat(4)} ${value.substr(value.length - 4, value.length)}`;
}
```

```html
<span [innerHTML]="cardNo | mask: true"></span>
```

**Note**: If you want bigger bullet points, simply replace `&bull;` with `&#x25cf;`.

Comment: How to replace XXXX with bullet special character, I can use input type= password ?

Comment: @hafizi - You need to use the Unicode character for that. Check my updated answer.